# CCMoveTo has no effect on my CCSprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

all. I have some function "tetrisl" in this function I want to move tetris sprites down:

```
-(void)tetrisL:(ccTime)dt {

    Tetris *s = [[Tetris node]initWithArraySize:4];
    [s createL];
    for (CCSprite *new in s.tetrisArray) {
        [self addChild:new];

        id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(new.position.x,0)];
        [new runAction: actionMove];

    }
    [s release];
}
```

But it's don't work. I think because I try to move different sprites in same Action. How can i fix it? Thanks

Here is Tetris class

```
@interface Tetris : CCNode {

    NSMutableArray *tetrisArray;
    Blocks *tempBlock;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tetrisArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Blocks *tempBlock;
-(id)initWithArraySize:(int)sz;
-(void)createL;


@implementation Tetris
@synthesize tetrisArray;
@synthesize tempBlock;

-(id)initWithArraySize:(int)sz {

    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        tetrisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:sz];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)createL {

    int xPos = 10;
    int yPos = 460;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tempBlock = [[Blocks node]initWithType:1];
        tempBlock.blockSprite.position = ccp(xPos,yPos);
        [tetrisArray addObject:tempBlock.blockSprite];
        xPos = xPos + 26;
        [tempBlock release];

    }

}

-(void)dealloc {

    [tempBlock release];
    [tetrisArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: other than it not working, what is actually happening when you run that code? Are the sprites not added to your scene, do they appear but not move?

Comment: yes, they appear but not move

Comment: can you give more information on your Tetris class and createL method?

Comment: i really dont see a problem with the Tetris class... maybe it has to do with calling the schedule method.. are the sprites appearing after calling `[self addchild:new]`? or is their initial position offscreen?

Comment: yes sprites appear after calling [self addChild:new] and after that application crashed (

Comment: Could you please post your link to download your source code , because i am new to game development in android, i plan to start up with Cocos2d framework, if you have any sample or tutorial please help me out... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can't assign one action to different sprites. One action - one sprite. You can use action copy function to dublicate actions.

But in your case action creates in loop, so it must be different actions...
may be problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Defferent sprites cann't execute the same action at the same time, so you should copy the action, like following code:

```
  sprite->runAction((CCActionInterval*)aciotn->copy->autoRelease());
```